# Debugger and Intellitrace show truncated text in text viewer for long SqlCommand.CommandText

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, entity-framework, intellitrace, watch-window

I'm trying to find out what the text is of a `select` statement made against SQL Server using Entity Framework. The `CommandText` property under both IntelliTrace and the debugger truncate the text to exactly 4096 characters in the text view. Is there a way to see all of it or to configure these tools to at least raise the limit?

Update: This still occurs as part of the VS 2015 Diagnostic Tools.

Comment: Is it the value column that's being truncated to 4096?

Comment: No, the actual `CommandText` string property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134617/how-to-avoid-truncated-ef-query-in-the-intellitrace-events For future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same limitation.

I started using the [MS-SQL profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213327.aspx) to see the entire command text. There are other profilers and NuGet packages to be able to see the entire command.