# How to avoid truncated EF query in the IntelliTrace events?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, intellitrace

I'm trying to debug an entity framework query. But when the query gets too big, the query showed in the intelliTrace appears truncated (only part of the  query is displayed, even if I copy and paste it in a notepad). Is there any workaround to get the entire query generated by EF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot showing an example of the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get around this as I am seeing the same issue

Comment: No. Didn't find any.

Answer (score 7):

It has been some time but it might help others.

take a look at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\en\collectionplan.xml

14 refers to VS 2015
 Around line 266 you will see

```
<DiagnosticEventSpecification>
```

go a bit furter and locate `<DataQueries>`
Inside those there is a:

```
<DataQuery index="0" maxSize="4096" type="String" name="Command Text" _locID="dataquery.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader.CommandText" _locAttrData="name" query="_commandText"></DataQuery>
```

Change the `maxSize="4096"` to what ever fits your need.

Comment: So much better than going through the gazillion records of SQL profiler!

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2017, I found the collectionplan.xml in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\en.

Then I needed to restart VS.